# SwiftUI .focused() View Modifier not working .onAppear

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to get the new iOS 15.0 `.focused()` View Modifier to execute when a SwiftUI View appears:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct MainView: View {
    @State var subViewIsDisplayed = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Button(action: { subViewIsDisplayed.toggle() }) {
                Text("Trigger SubView")
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $subViewIsDisplayed) {
            SubView()
        }
    }
}

struct SubView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
    @State var text = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button(action: { dismiss() }) {
                    Image(systemName: "xmark")
                }
            }
            Spacer()
            TextField("Please autofocus :(", text: $text)
                .focused($isFocused)
            Spacer()
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.isFocused = true
        }
    }
}

struct MainView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MainView()
    }
}
```

On my physical device, triggering "SubView" doesn't bring up the keyboard (as I would expect from `.focused`). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what about the simulator does it work?

Comment: I think this is a bug. There was another question like this last week I think and The code worked fine on my Macbook Simulator but I got the impression that it didn't work on that OP's system. I can't get this code to work at all.

Comment: iOS 15 is released and it still doesn't work. It's like they don't even try using their own software before they release it.

Comment: To everyone saying this is a bug, it is sadly not. This is clearly stated in the documentation for `.onAppear()`: *"[...] the action closure completes before the first rendered frame appears."* That is exactly why the accepted answer works, because it runs on the immediate next UI cycle (which is already past the first frame rendering event).

Answer (score 10):

```
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                isFocused = true
            }
        }
```

DispatchQueue.main.async, as always will do the trick

[image]

Comment: Plus 1 For the image.

Comment: DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.7) this code block solved my issue

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

```
.onAppear {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.7){
        isFocused = true
    } //Delayed execution of 0.7s
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like another SwiftUI bug to me. Here's a workaround.

All my changes to your example code are in the `onAppear` closure.

I'm getting it to work at `i=7` on both simulator and device.

```
struct SubView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
    @State var text = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button(action: { dismiss() }) {
                    Image(systemName: "xmark")
                }
            }
            Spacer()
            TextField("Please autofocus :(", text: $text)
                .focused($isFocused)
            Spacer()
        }
        .onAppear {
            Task {
                for i in 1...20 {
                    isFocused = true
                    if isFocused {
                        print("The set finally stuck. i=\(i)")
                        break
                    }
                    await Task.sleep(100_000_000)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```